# Replacing an old LOCAL notification with a new one

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

The application sends notifications to the user. I need a new notification to delete the old one. Not that the old notifications were deleted when you log into the application. Namely, so that a new notification replaces the old one. For example, the application sent notification_1, and after an hour notification_2. Thus, you only need the user to see notifications_2.

now i do so

```
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
     dateComponents.second! += 20
    createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test 0", notificationId: "1")
    for i in 1...2 {
        dateComponents.second! += 1
        createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test \(i)", notificationId: "2")
    }
    dateComponents.minute! += 2
    createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test 00", notificationId: "2")
```

and function

```
    func createLocalPush(dateMatching: DateComponents, alertTitle: String, alertBody: String, notificationId: String) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = alertBody
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = .default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateMatching, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationId, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(#function, "error add notification", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print(#function, "add request ok")
        }
    }
}
```

but the application only gives pushes "test_0" and "test_00". Why does the application skip push "test_1" and "test_2", and not replace them with each other? **And how to make the following remove the coming?**

Comment: as long as you use the same notification ID it should replace the old one

Comment: @Scriptable I understand it. therefore I use "notificationId:" 2 "". but the app skips the notifications test_1 and test_2. And it displays only "test_00". Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
     dateComponents.second! += 20
    createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test 0", notificationId: "1")
    for i in 1...2 {
        dateComponents.second! += 1
        createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test \(i)", notificationId: "2")
    }
    dateComponents.minute! += 2
    createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test 00", notificationId: "2")
```

In the for loop above you create notifications with ID 2. So each one you create will overwrite the previous one.

Then you have

```
createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test 00", notificationId: "2")
```

Which replaces the last one you created in your for loop.

Looking at your code I would only expect to receive 2 notifications... 1 & 2.

If you change your for loop to something like

```
for i in 1...2 {
   dateComponents.second! += 1
   createLocalPush(dateMatching: dateComponents, alertTitle: "test", alertBody: "test \(i)", notificationId: "test_\(i)")
}
```

Then all of them would show

Comment: Your answer is clear to me. but my question was a little different.
Then is it possible to somehow schedule notifications so that the test_00 notification replaces the test_1 notification?
Example, at 12:00 the user saw "test_1", and after an hour "test_00", the notification "test_1" should disappear.

Comment: you could just set it to repeat after 1 hour. otherwise you would need to create the new notification 1 hour later and use the same ID. you can't create a notification and tell it to change at a later point, you need to replace it

Comment: correctly understand that there is no way to replace earlier local notifications with later ones, except how to do them through "repeat"?

Comment: something like this... `let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3600, repeats: true)`

Comment: Unfortunately, UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger does not allow you to create a notification on a specific date. For example, at 18:00. Yes, you can calculate the date difference, but then there is no need for the repeats flag.
Nonetheless, thanks for the help!